# Are there any PDP-8 assemblers that create linkable object files?

Tags: assembly, pdp-8, link-editor

I am currently writing a compiler for the PDP-8.  The compiler is going to translate source code into PDP-8 assembly code that calls some runtime routines to perform high-level functions such as managing call frames.

I am currently using Douglas Jones' PAL assembler which turns out to be rather annoying for my use case as it

- does not support underscores or dollar signs in identifiers
- does not allow the assembly code to be split into multiple files

As a consequence, the compiler has to do some copy-paste action to combine the runtime code with the compiled program.  Linking is also not easily possible.

Is there an assembler for the PDP-8 that provides an object-file based process with a final linking stage so my compiler could emit object files that are linked into a single core image by a linker?

Comment: Not an answer, because I have no PDP-8 experience, but a suggestion: you may find a linker in one of the existing language systems for the PDP-8, such as the FORTRAN IV for OS/8. If so, it will presumably give clues about assemblers you can use with it.

Comment: There are a few PDP emulators running Unix, would that fit your (temporary?) needs?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I don't think they ever made UNIX for the PDP-8.  Are you thinking about the PDP-11?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PiDP-8 project has a wonderful [Field Guide to PDP-8 Assemblers](https://tangentsoft.com/pidp8i/wiki?name=A+Field+Guide+to+PDP-8+Assemblers), which reviews most (all?) of the PDP-8 assemblers available.

SMAL, SABR and RALF have linkable objects that may fit your needs.  A [partial C cross-compiler for the PDP-8](http://so-much-stuff.com/pdp8/C/C.php) exists, and uses SMAL.